# Possible query with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a8a6c3c48933256cfd8368"),
    "Title" : "T1",
    "TitleData" : [ 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f96"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9c"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9d"),
            "Res" : 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a8a6c3c48933256cfd8369"),
    "Word" : "T2",
    "WordsData" : 
    [ 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f96"),
            "Res" : 2         
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a8a6c3c48933256cfd8360"),
    "Word" : "T3",
    "WordsData" : 
    [ 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7"),
            "Res" : 0         
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I need to make a query to extract only documents which:
a) Contains in TitleData `UserId` = "57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b" AND "57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7"
b) At least one of the 2 TitleData element must have MatchType != 2
So the final result will be:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a8a6c3c48933256cfd8360"),
    "Title" : "T3",
    "TitleData" : 
    [ 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),
            "Res" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7"),
            "Res" : 0         
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What i can do, is filter results for the a) criteria with the following instruction:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({TitleData:{$elemMatch:{UserId:ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),UserId:ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7")}}})
```

but i can't find a way to filter with the b) condition in AND with a).
Any suggestion?

**[EDIT]**
This solution works better for point a).

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({
$and: [{
  TitleData: {
    $elemMatch: {
      UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b")          
    }
  }
},{
  TitleData: {
    $elemMatch: {
      UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7")          
    }
  }
}, 
{
  TitleData: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $ne: {
        "Res": 2
      }
    }
  }
}]
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$and`:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({
$and: [{
  TitleData: {
    $elemMatch: {
      UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),
      UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7")
    }
  }
}, {
  TitleData: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $ne: {
        "Res": 2
      }
    }
  }
}]
}));
```

Test output from console with your collection objects:

```
> db.collection.find({ $and: [{     TitleData: {       $elemMatch: {         UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),          UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7")       }     }   },{ TitleData: { $elemMatch: { $ne: { "Res": 2 } } }}]});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a8a6c3c48933256cfd8368"), "Title" : "T1", "TitleData" : [     {   "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"),    "Res" : 2 },    {   "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7"),    "Res" : 2 },    {   "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f96"),    "Res" : 2 },    {   "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9c"),    "Res" : 2 },    {   "UserId" : ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9d"),    "Res" : 0 } ] }
```

**EDIT** Didn't add all of console output...

Comment: Yeah ! The solution is good! Now I'm trying to implement it in .NET, but returned always the error 'Duplicate Element Name' for UserId. Anyway, your solution works! Thank you !

Comment: @Marco Why did you un-accept, is it not working as expected?

Comment: I rewrite your solution in order to fix the a) point. Your solution for b) part is correct.

Comment: You can't have two `UserId` fields in the same object, only the second one will be used. Try `obj = { UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96f9b"), UserId: ObjectId("57a87f5cc48933119cb96fa7") }` in the shell to see what happens.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Strangely, this works fine in my console... **EDIT**: I think you're confused. This isn't an insertion of an object. This is a `$elemMatch` expression, which can have multiple values of the same field to test against.

Comment: The query will run without errors, but both `UserId` values aren't used. Just the second one. JS objects can't have two fields with the same name.

Comment: I see, very good point that makes a lot of sense. Should I use an array instead?