# Invalid query in mongo c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I've this query:

```
string jsonquery = "{
$and : [{
        WordsData : {
            $elemMatch : {
                UserId : ObjectId('57a87f5cc48933119cb96f93'),
                UserId : ObjectId('57a87f5cc48933119cb96f94')
            }
        }
    }, {
        WordsData : {
            $not : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    MatchType : 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
}"
```

if i execute it in a mongo console works correctly!
I'm trying to run this query in a c# program. Running the same json query i got the following error:

```
BsonDocument doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonquery);
[Error] --> {"Duplicate element name 'UserId'."}
```

Why doesn't works in c# ?

Comment: You can't have two `UserId` fields in your `$elemMatch` object. The shell is just ignoring one of them.

Comment: Why this problem only in .NET ? Because the same query works correctly for example in RoboMongo client console! 
How can i obtain the same result without passing "UserId" multiple times for the same $elemMatch?
What i'm trying to do, is a query which return all documents that have in WordsData array one element with UserId = {57a87f5cc48933119cb96f93} and one other element with UserId = {57a87f5cc48933119cb96f94}

Comment: could you post example document?

Comment: @profesor79: see my previous post [Possible query with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854787/possible-query-with-mongodb/38854921#38854921)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest multiple `$elemMatch` inside of a `$and` expression. See this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014699/mongodb-multiple-elemmatch) for an example.

Think of JSON as a map -- if you have duplicate keys they are going to override each other and cause errors and/or unexpected results.

Comment: You are suggesting something like this:  
`{ $and: [{ WordsData: { $elemMatch: { UserId: ObjectId(\"{0}\") } } },{ WordsData: { $elemMatch: { UserId: ObjectId(\"{1}\") } } }`